# Concept of dividing ui from logic in js project

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

i would like to do refactoring of some project which I have to take care from now. 3/4 of project is made in JavaScript+jQuery. All JS code is about 5k lines. The main developer of this project combined logic with DOM elements, for ex.

```
var UPPERTOOLBAR = {
    setDialog : function() {
        this.$popup = $('#toolbar').dialog({
            autoOpen : false,
            height : 'auto',
            maxHeight : 450,
            resizable : false,
            stack : false,
            width : 300,
            zIndex : 997,
            position : {
                my : "right top+205",
                at : "right top",
                of : window
            }
        });
    }};
```

and after few lines I get same code but for other HTML element :

```
var LEGEND = {
    setDialog : function() {
        this.$popup = $('#toolbar').dialog({
            autoOpen : false,
            height : 'auto',
            maxHeight : 450,
            resizable : false,
            stack : false,
            width : 300,
            zIndex : 997,
            position : {
                my : "right top+205",
                at : "right top",
                of : window
            }
        });
    }};
```

or event handler

```
        $('#searchpanel').animate(self.__getDivHeight(mode), 'slow', 'swing', function() {
            $('#searchform').css('display', 'block');
            $('#searchheader').css('background-position', '-864px 0px');
            self.shown = true;
        });
```

and then he copy past same code but with another selector....
Becouse of [DRY](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY) and problems with maintaining this code for me, I'm wondering if it would be better to create some object like for ex. GUI and place there methods for most repeatable methods from main code... for ex:

```
var GUI = {
  setDialog:function(selector){

   $(selector).dialog({

//all the coniguration
})
}}
```

and so on...
first, do you think this global idea is good? What problems can I expect? Maybe there is another solution?
I'm worrying about another thing, what if there will be a lot of lets say dialogs with different configuration?.. should I store it in GUI object or maybe separate in objects which would call GUI object method?
I would be glad for constructive opinions. thanks! :)

Comment: Look into knockoutjs, great library for JavaScript mvvm

Answer (score 1):

I recommend refactoring the application to use AngularJS. With Angular, you will still write  jQuery like you have above, but will do so in an isolated environment called a `Directive`.

A directive is a way to attach behavior to an HTML element by name or by class. For instance,

```
<uppertoolbar>
```

You will find jQuery disappearing from your HTML and reappearing in .JS files where it belongs.

http://www.egghead.io is a great place to start.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive when you're ready to start writing directives.

Answer (score 1):

I am a fan of DRY, and try to make my code fit into it when I can. In the above, "SetDialog" points to an 'anonymous' function, that is, a function without a name of its own. But there is nothing preventing you from writing the function once, and referring to it:

```
function realSetDialog() {
    this.$popup = $('#toolbar').dialog({
        autoOpen : false,
        height : 'auto',
        maxHeight : 450,
        resizable : false,
        stack : false,
        width : 300,
        zIndex : 997,
        position : {
            my : "right top+205",
            at : "right top",
            of : window
        }
    });
}


var UPPERTOOLBAR = {
  setDialog : realSetDialog
};

var LEGEND = {
  setDialog : realSetDialog
};
```

Then if you need to make changes to the setDialog function, you only need to make changes in one place.

NOTICE: no parenthesis after the function name. In C/C++ terms, this amounts to a "pointer" to the actual function. Took me a while to wrap my head around this quirk of Javascript. It also still parses the 'this' properly, unless it is called directly like "realSetDialog();".

I will say that, for the most part, there isn't "code" in these blocks. Certainly they used the function keyword, but that is/was commonly used as shorthand for "make me an object". Then the object itself has only data in it, making it more 'presentation' than 'code', though I agree on the winceworthiness of the repetition.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah pointer is key word here. it is the same idea which came from to my head, but troubles starts if for ex. UPPERTOOLBAR width have to be 300px and LEGEND toolbar width 150px, so I have to create another object with configuration (it would do not big change at all), or pass them as arguments to function, but there would be to much arguments and it just would not be handy..

Comment: Actually, Javascript makes a pseudo "named argument" system pretty easy. Have the function accept one argument, which is an object with the properties you want different from default. Then you just LEGEND.setDialog({width:"150px"}) while UPPERTOOLBAR.setDialog() sticks with defaults. Inner code like " width: o.width?'300px':o.width; ".  Just a little boilerplate to get it running, and since it is a single function such work is not tedious.